# Connecting mylyn task list to repository

Tags: connection, repository, mylyn

I'm new to mylyn.

It seems I should connect to a repository, should I connect to eclipse.org to store bugs/tasks on my projects?  Is information stored secure/private?

In the properties for task repository, I enter 
Server: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs
Label: Eclipse.org
User ID: ...
Password: ...

When I click validate settings, I keep getting
"I/O Error occurred while communicating with https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs."

Via chrome, I have logged into the account using the creditials.

What should I do next to be able to connect to the repository?

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems I should connect to a repository, should I connect to
>   eclipse.org to store bugs/tasks on my projects? Is information stored
>   secure/private?

NO! You must create your own Bugzilla installation. You can also use other tracking system like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) or [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview).

But you can also use Mylyn local. It is possible to create **local** tasks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tim Krueger says it all. Additionally though, getting an IO Exception on trying to connect to the Eclipse.org Bugzilla instance is weird. You might want to use the webUI to submit a bug to this Bugzilla about it.
Which leads me to my second point: the eclipse.org Bugzilla is used for bugs on all those eclipse.org projects. Mylyn being one of them. It is not for private tasks.

So local tasks are your best bet. And if you need collaboration, try installing one of the many repositories where there are Mylyn connectors for. Trac and Bugzilla probably being a good choice as they are mature connectors, and a free servers.